# Spring security to recover the user name after intercept

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, post, spring-security

I have a login form that posts to a URL that is intercepted by acegi-security, but I want to have access to the user name at some point on the server. Is there anything I can do?

EDIT

Using acegi-security-1.0.3

Thanks

Comment: what version of Spring (acegi) Security are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here: http://java-x.blogspot.com/2006/12/spring-security-with-acegi-security.html
You should be able to get the Username out of the SecurityContextHolder context  by fetching the Authentication.

```
 <%= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() %>
```